# Salvar formulário em arquivo txt

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

É possível salvar um formulário em arquivo TXT?

Vou explicar... Tenho um site para capação de dados como NOME e EMAIL, apenas.

Gostaria de salvar no TXT a cada nova inserção. Ficando assim:

```
1| Fulano - fulano@site.com.br
2| Sicrano - sicrano @site.com.br
3| Baltrano - baltrano @site.com.br
.
.
.
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Sim é possível, você poder ver como funciona a leitura e criação de arquivos na sua linguagem de programação, com isso, basta criar a função ou método que vai ser enviado o post do formulário, é lá você cria seu arquivo no formato desejado. Não utilizo o php mais não deve ser difícil a criação de arquivos por lá.

Comment: Olhe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641015/really-simple-php-form-to-save-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode utilizar isso com o exemplo do código abaixo (em PHP).

```
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

O ideal é que você utilize uma base de dados para gravação de dados, você pode utilizar o Firebase Realtime Database para esse processo, o método de implementação é super simples e você encontra muito material "pronto" no Github.

Ou se preferir, você pode utilizar uma API que disponibilizo open source no Github para utilizar como "getting started" em projetos: https://github.com/andersoonluan/graphql-nodejs-api

Um abraço e boa sorte!